# What order should I watch the Digimon Adventure series?

Tags: suggested-order, digimon

So, as far as I know, the content covering Digimon Adventure is as follows:

1. *Digimon Adventure*
2. *Digimon Adventure 02*
3. *Digimon: The Movie*
4. *Digimon Adventure tri*
5. *Digimon Adventure: Last Evolution Kizuna*
6. *Digimon Adventure:/Digimon Adventure 2020*

Since *Digimon Adventure: Last Evolution Kizuna* is meant to be the end of the Adventure story, I wanted to watch the whole Adventure timeline **from start to finish**.

Also, I know that in *Digimon Fusion/Xros Wars*, apparently Tai, Matt, & Joe from *Digimon Adventure* and Davis from *Adventure 02* appear in the third season, The Boy Hunters Who Leapt Through Time, but Marcus from *Digimon: Data Squad*, Takato from *Digimon Tamers*, and the kids from *Digimon Frontier* appear as well.

So, do I also need to watch Tamers, Frontier, the 3 seasons of Fusion/Xros Wars, and Data Squad as well?

What about *Digimon Universe: App Monsters* and *Digimon Adventure:/Digimon Adventure* (2020)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically hit the nail on the head with the original list--you've listed almost all related tv series/movies in the *Adventure* canon in about the order that they came out and are chronological in-universe.  There is a movie, *Revenge of Diaboromon*, that takes place after *Digimon Adventure 02,* that you missed, but I myself had forgotten about it. You would be able to keep up fine and miss out on nothing by watching it in your order.

Now, *Digimon: the Movie* is the English release of three different animated features smashed up into one 90-minute movie: *Digimon Adventure* is technically a prequel to the first season (and, in Japan, was released prior to the series), *Our War Game* takes place after the first season, and (deep breath) *Digimon Hurricane Landing!!/Transcendent Evolution!! The Golden Digimentals* takes place midway through *02*.  So, if you insist on watching the English movie, you'd probably want to watch it before episode 20 or so of *02.*  As far as I know, the individual features have never gotten an English release, though you could certainly find fansubbed versions if you looked.

The other seasons are completely unrelated to the *Adventure* canon, although most are worth watching anyway, if you have the time and inclination.  As you said, the climax of *Fusion/Xros Wars* involves all of the previous seasons' characters, including the *Adventure* kids, popping in to cameo, but this doesn't affect the *Adventure* plotline in any way.  I think you'd be hard-pressed to find anyone who considers their appearances part of the *Adventure* canon.

*Digimon Universe: App Monsters* is another self-contained universe.  *Digimon Adventure 2020* is a hard reboot of the Digimon Adventure plotline.